Different output from pdflatex, dvipdfm, dvisvgm and dvips. (TikZ arrowhead)
Why do TikZ arrowheads in this example look different depending on which way I compile the file?
I'm using TeX Live 2023 on Ubuntu. My source test.tex looks like this:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.5cm, stealth-, draw=red]
    \draw(0,0) -- (1,2);
    \node[red] {};
    \draw(2,0) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

test_dvisvgm.tex is identical except that it has \documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone} on the first line.
test_dvipdfm.tex is identical except that it has \documentclass[dvipdfm]{standalone} on the first line.
Here are the results:

pdflatex test.tex



latex test_dvipdfm.tex && dvipdfm test_dvipdfm.dvi



latex test_dvisvgm.tex && dvisvgm test_dvisvgm.dvi



latex test.tex && dvips test.dvi



This seems to be caused by issues in the backends of TikZ. If you omit \documentclass option dvisvgm and convert the DVI file with dvisvgm, you get the same result as with dvips. So, at least, it's not a bug in dvisvgm. :-)

set also the fill color to red: fill=red,draw=red
